# May I ask someone who has a reputation of at least 3K to move some of my questions to other StackExchange sites?

Tags: support

One of my first questions does not fit the Q&A of StackOverflow. Therefore I would like to move it to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) in this case. However, a reputation of at least 3K is required. Is it OK to ask someone who has a reputation of at least 3K to move some of my questions?

Comment: Note that if a question is older than 60 days it cannot be migrated, even by moderators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the reputation for some action, for example closing as 'belongs to the other side', use **flags**.

Note that 3K users self doesn't have the priviledges to move questions to other side. Only the mods do. Regular users can only **vote to close** with the reason that the question belongs to the other side, using a few predefined migration paths.

It still requires **at least 5** regular users' votes, or single moderator vote.

Comment: The [question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932154/silent-install-of-vagrant-to-preferred-directory-on-windows) cannot be migrated, even by moderators.  It is more than 60 days old.  As such it will have to stay on SO.